# Как отправить и принять unsigned long long c++

Tags: c++

Уже три часа пытаюсь найти решение, необходимо с помощью наименьшего байтов отправить от клиента на сервер число unsigned long long,

Делаю так

Клиент:

```
unsigned long long n = 18446744073709551500;
send(sock, (char *)n, 8, 0);
```

Сервер:

```
char t[7];
recv(sock, t, 8, 0);
unsigned long long n;
memcpy(&n, t, sizeof(unsigned long long));
printf("%llu\n", n);
```

Сервер вывел: 14757395258967641141

Пробовал уже много чего, может кто-нибудь знает, я в си не силён простите за глупый вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пропустили указатель, достаточно добавить **&** в код клиента:

```
unsigned long long n = 18446744073709551500;
send(sock, (char*)&n, sizeof(n), 0);
```

Код сервера:

```
unsigned long long n;
recv(sock, (char*)&n, sizeof(n), 0);
printf("%llu\n", n);
```

Comment: Это был первый вариант который я и взял из учебника, но студия мне выдала вот это: 
"аргумент типа "unsigned long long * несовместим с параметром типа "char *"

Может надо что-то сменить в настройках?

Comment: в учебнике было

Клиент: send(sock, (char *)&n, sizeof(n), 0);

Сервер: recv(sock, &n, sizeof(n), 0);

Comment: upd: добавил кастинг к (char*)

Comment: Спасибо, для меня заработало

Answer (score 3):

Вы принимаете 8 байт в 7-байтный буфер, как минимум проблема может быть тут

Comment: Это было в качестве эксперимента, забыл исправить обратно, дело в том что выводилось одно и то же при любых размерах буфера